How to save pointers to data members with a different types in a container?
cppreference pointer page gives some examples of how to use pointers to data members. But what if I want to safe them in one container? For example:
class C {
   int i;
   double d;
};

std::vector<???> v{&C::i, &C::d};

I know I can use std::any for it, but maybe there's something like void * for simple pointers?
And a connected question. std::any, as I understand, saves typeid to check whether cast is bad. While using pointers to data members, can I use it to get the right cast, smth like:
C c;
c.*(std::cast<??? &C::*>(v[0])) = 42;

I'll appreciate some links to read about pointers to data members, there's too little I was able to find!

What is the original and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need to store pointers to individual member variables? How does that solve the original problem?

If you want to throw away your type information only to put it back later with a cast, you are doing something wrong,

But what if I want to safe them in one container? -- XY Problem?  The "X" we would like to know, the "Y" is you wanting to store pointers to data members.

@Someprogrammerdude I want to create an analog of golang json tags for parsing json files. Particularly, I want to create a class adapter, which would store bindings between name of json field (std::string) and where to write this field in a class (data member pointer). Then, given a class instance, I want to iterate through the vector and fill class instance with json values.

@PaulMcKenzie Yeah, you're right, but this question is not only about dealing with an original issue, but also about learning ways of working with a thing I couldn't find enough on the web

@Nkamil I have no idea about Golang.  How do existing C++ based JSON parsers work?  What you want to do sounds like reflection, and C++ does not have this capability built-in.

Instead of storing a pointer to a data field, store a std::function that receives a string representation of the data and sets that data field.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Can you clarify, please? How I'll be creating class-adapter then? Passing a user-specified std::function for each field of a class I want deserialise to?

@PaulMcKenzie yeah, I'm trying to overcome an issue of lack of reflection in C++, with explicitly filling a class-adapter (helper) with fields and name of members a class (I want to deserialise to) has :)

std::vector<std::function<void(C&, std::string_view)>> v { [](C& c, std::string_view s){c.i = std::stoi(s);}, [](C& c, std::string_view s){c.d = std::stod(s);}}; (not tested).


How to save pointers to data members with a different types in a container?

You have to enumerate all possible types. C++ is statically typed langauge. For example:
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
struct C {
   int i;
   double d;
};
std::vector<std::variant<int C::*, double C::*>> v{&C::i, &C::d};


maybe there's something like void * for simple pointers?

(Sadly) There is not. Pointers to members are magic enough.

can I use it to get the right cast, smth like:

Yes, you can use it "like" that.
#include <vector>
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
struct C {
   int i;
   double d;
};
std::vector<std::any> v{&C::i, &C::d};
int main() {
    C c;
    c.i = 1;
    std::cout << c.*std::any_cast<int C::*>(v[0]) << '\n';
}

